# Async await doesn't stop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've a problem when i use async await in react-native
when i'm trying to fetch data from firebase and update the state, it's updating the state spamming without stopping
here is the code in the contextApi

```
 const getProduct= async()=>{
        let loadedProducts=[]
        try{
            const responseData= await fetch('https://shopapp-b1704.firebaseio.com/products.json')
            if(!responseData.ok){
                new Error("something wrong happened!")
            }
       const resData= await responseData.json()
      
       for (const key in resData){
           loadedProducts.push(new Product(key,'u1',
           resData[key].title, resData[key].imageUrl,
           resData[key].description,
            +resData[key].price))
       }
       }catch(err){
           throw err;
       }
       console.log(loadedProducts)
       setAvailableProducts(loadedProducts)
```

and this is the code in products screen

```
const loading=useCallback(async()=>{
    getProducts()
  },[])

  useEffect(()=>{
    loading()
  },[])
```

Comment: what does loading do ?

Comment: to use it later for refresh the page by adding pull to refresh

Comment: does it depend on any of the state data ?

Comment: depends on just making await of getProducts function to finish, did you understand what i mean?